# How do I refer to the root Wordpress directory INSIDE a Javascript file

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I've got a javascript file and somewhere within the code I have this line:

```
$(".section-divider.ornament").append('<img src="wp-content/themes/blackandwhite/img/divider-glyph.png" alt="" />');
```

I know it's not best practice to hard code in the directory like that, but I don't know how else to do it since:
a) as far as I know, PHP doesn't work within JS files.
b) leaving it as "img/divider-glyph.png" (I've tried both with and without a leading '/') doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

I don't really like Wordpress so I keep my distance but I believe you can use this function to get the Wordpress base installation directory:

```
<?php
get_bloginfo('wpurl');
?>
```

You can use that to add this information to the DOM, for instance the `<body>` tag:

```
<body data-base-dir="<?php echo get_bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>">
```

Then your JS could read this information:

```
var baseDir = $("body").data("data-base-dir");
```

Note than jQuery's `.data()` method will only cache `data-*` attributes that exist when jQuery loads, so updating an attribute or adding it after jQuery loads will require using `.attr("data-*")`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply- unfortunately that doesn't get me all the way to the root directory of the THEME. I need the 'wp-content/themes/blackandwhite' part to be captured within the url.

Comment: @NickJankowski The process will work, just find the PHP function that outputs that exact information. It most likely exists.

Comment: @NickJankowski I assume you found the correct function, if you did, what was it?

Comment: bloginfo('template_url')